# Sending SMS Through Serial port in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using Serial port to send sms through a GSM/Modem .My code is working with single sms. The problem arise when I try to send sms in bulk. Then no sms are sent  and no exceptions are generated.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO.Ports;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 namespace program.cs
 {
    public class Class1
 {
    public string[] strarray = new string[10];
    SerialPort serialport1 = new SerialPort();
    string com = "COM8";
    int mybaudrate = 9600;


    //this.strarray =System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();


    public void getports()
    {
        this.strarray = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    }

    public bool connetport() 
    {
        bool Isopen;
        serialport1.Close();
        try
        {
            if (!this.serialport1.IsOpen) 
            {
                this.serialport1.PortName = com;

                this.serialport1.Open();
                this.serialport1.BaudRate = mybaudrate;
                this.serialport1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
                this.serialport1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
                this.serialport1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

                 Isopen= serialport1.IsOpen;




            }

            Isopen = true;


            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Isopen = false;
            throw ex;
        }
        return Isopen;   
    }

    public void sendsms() 
    {
        try
        {

            if (this.serialport1.IsOpen)
            {

                // to send bulk sms


                serialport1.BaseStream.Flush();

                int loop = 0;
                int howmany = 0;

                howmany = 200;



                while (loop < howmany)
                {

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500);

                    string cb = char.ConvertFromUtf32(26);
                    this.serialport1.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                   this.serialport1.Write("AT+CSCA=servicecenter\r   
                   \n");//Ufone              Service Center                    
                    this.serialport1.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + "03468916446" + "\"\r\n");// 
                    this.serialport1.Write("hello" + cb);//message text
                    message sending

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500);

                    loop++;


                }
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sent Number" + loop);

                serialport1.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            serialport1.Close();
            throw ex;
        }


    }







}
```

}

Class1 above is used to connect and send sms

Code For  Main Program

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool check;
    Class1 obj = new Class1();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        check = obj.connetport();
        MessageBox.Show("Connecton Status" + check);
        obj.sendsms();
        MessageBox.Show("have completed");
    }
}
```

I have invested a lot of time on solving this problem but without success. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Understand what Thread.Sleep does before you use it. That loop will take 23.3 minutes to complete the way you have it now. Also what errors are you getting. Also don't call serialport1.Close() in the beginning of connectport. Also work on your naming and formatting, like camelCase.

Comment: I am getting no errors and execution is colmpleted without any errors or exception

Comment: And i think Thread.sleep (pause the process for  these milliseconds)

Comment: if you set "howmany" to 1 and comment out //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500); is the sms going out? I agree with N00B.NET, something is wrong on that 3.5 seconds sleep.

Comment: Check your serial port settings also. I.e make sure the parity and stop bits match the modems. You also haven't set the data size, which should be something  like serialport1.DataBits = 8.

Comment: And 3500 milliseconds = 3.5 seconds. You do that twice per loop. 3.5 * 2 * 200 / 60 = 23.33 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tool like Portmon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) to make sure your messages are being recieved by the modem.

If they are you may want to check with your carrier as a lot of them blackhole bulk sms messages. (to avoid spammers and the like)